# How to: XMLDocument.GetElementsByTagName() in PHP?

Tags: c#, php, xml

I have written a downloader for Tumblr in C#. But I want to code it in PHP too. Everything works, but I don't know how to get all XML nodes out of a `simplexml` doc with the photo-url tag. 
My old working C# Code:

```
while(****){
    doc.Load("http://" + Blogname + ".tumblr.com/api/read?start=" + start + "&num=50");
    list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("photo-url");
```

"list" contains all XML Elements with the photo-url tag.

PHP:

```
$output = simplexml_load_file("http://" . $blogname . ".tumblr.com/api/read?start=" . $start . "&num=50");
$list = ??????
```

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SimpleXML's [`xpath()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) method passing XPath expression of form `//elementName` to find elements of certain name, anywhere in the document :

```
$list = $output->xpath('//photo-url');
```

Alternatively, you can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of SimpleXML, which has the exact same method [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php).